# Disregarding blank cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a code that does exactly what I want it to except that it also changes the colors of the matching blanks. I am wondering what I can add to the code so blank cells are not marked.

```
beginrow = 2
First = 0
FirstLast = 0
Second = 0
SecondLast = 0

For z = 2 To finalrow
    If Cells(z, 9).Value = Cells(1 + z, 9).Value And Cells(z, 10).Value <> Cells(1 + z, 10).Value And Cells(z, 12).Value = Cells(1 + z, 12).Value Then
        First = z
        FirstLast = First + 1
    End If
    If Cells(z, 9).Value = Cells(1 + z, 9).Value And Cells(z, 12).Value <> Cells(1 + z, 12).Value Then
            Second = z
            SecondLast = Second + 1
            endKnown = True
    End If
    If endKnown = True Then
        For arownumber = beginrow To First 'need to find the rownumbers that we compare with
            For change = 4 To 7
                For smrownumber = FirstLast To Second 'need to find the rownumbers for comparing
                    For across = 4 To 7
                        CellA = Cells(arownumber, change)
                        CellB = Cells(smrownumber, across)
                        match = IIf(CellA = CellB, "yes", "no")
                        If match = "yes" Then
                            Cells(arownumber, change).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                            Cells(smrownumber, across).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                        End If
                    Next across
                Next smrownumber
            Next change
        Next arownumber
        endKnown = False
        If SecondLast <> 0 Then
            beginrow = SecondLast
        End If
      End If
 Next z
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check for empty content before changing the `ColorIndex` of the `Interior` property of your `Cells` object.

```
'If your cell isn't empty then change background color
If(Cells(arownumber, change).Value <> "") Then
    Cells(arownumber, change).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End If

'If your cell isn't empty then change background color
If(Cells(smrownumber, across).Value <> "") Then
    Cells(smrownumber, across).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End If
```

Since `Cells` have to match before the condition is executed you could simplify things with something like this:

```
'If your cell isn't empty then change background color
If(Cells(arownumber, change).Value <> "" And Cells(smrownumber, across).Value <> "") Then
    Cells(arownumber, change).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    Cells(smrownumber, across).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End If
```

Comment: I may be wrong but I guess user is referring to `match = IIf(CellA = CellB, "yes", "no")` :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout You may be right actually. Both ways are right. You choose to not match empty cells while I just check if it was empty before changing the background :) Both solutions works for him I guess.

Comment: If one of them is blank then wouldn't it change the colour of just that if you do it separately? My understanding was to to color them if they both matched and were not empty or not color them at all... Anyways lets see what OP wants... Like I said I can be wrong :D

Comment: I used this solution but the other one seems like it would work equally as well.

Comment: @SiddharthRout If only one is blank then they wouldn't match so we wouldn't even have to go through the condition, right?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Both works but thank you for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this?

```
match = IIf((CellA = CellB) And (CellA <> ""), "yes", "no")
```

instead of

```
match = IIf(CellA = CellB, "yes", "no")
```